# WCS request for large raster

Tags: ogc, wcs, getcoverage

I am new to using OGC services and am attempting to extract a large tiff using the following URL request:

```
http://gis.dnr.alaska.gov/terrapixel/cubeserv/ortho?DATASTORE=SDMI_ORTHO_RGB&SERVICE=WCS&REQUEST=GetCoverage&
ACCEPTVERSIONS=2.0.1&coverageId=image_set&
SUBSET=E(101688,206499)&SUBSET=N(1005498,1100573)
```

At this extent, the resulting tiff would be ~13G, exceeding the server's max of 2G per request. However, when I try incrementing the extent to be withing the download bounds, I'm getting a 504 gateway timeout. I'd imagine that's probably still due to requesting a large amount of data, but I'd rather not go down the route of looping through 100 URL requests.

Obviously, I'd rather download the entire extent in one go, to avoid merging the rasters together, so ideally I can just add a new parameter that compresses the image. Like I said, I'm new to using WCS and not sure of the scope of capabilities/best practices so any advice would help a ton.

Comment: For a GetCoverage request you should use `version` not `acceptversions`.  The latter is for version negotiation on initial GetCapabilities, the former is for specifying version once version has been negotiated/decided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If service provider has set the size limit for GetCoverage request the only way to go is to download large area as smaller tiles. There are utilities which can help with looping, like GDAL WCS driver with the block size settings https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wcs.html.

> BlockXSize: The block width to use for block cached remote access.
>
> BlockYSize: The block height to use for block cached remote access.