# Specifying maximum dimensions for WCS 2.1.0 responses

Tags: ogc, wcs

I am hosting an unspecified WCS (2.1.0) server with limited resources. Is there a way to communicate a maximum result raster size (in width and height) to clients in the WCS (2) standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WCS 2.0 standard does not offer any proper alternative for that. The standard is written so that GetCoverage should work however big the coverage is. That is of course impossible with coverages that can be multi-terabytes in size and service providers must improvise their own solutions.

The best you can do by the standard is to mention the constraints in the service abstract, but WCS clients usually do not show them for the users, and free text abstract is not suitable for controlling  automatic processes.

A natural way to tell that the request is too large could be to throw an error message for GetCoverage, but the standard defines only 3 error codes for that operation:

- NoSuchCoverage
- InvalidAxisLabel
- InvalidSubsetting

In addition to the WCS specific codes, the WCS services should support also the error codes which are defined in another standard "OGC Web Services Common Standard 2.0" but I fear that it does not help in this case. One could think to (mis)use the error code InvalidParameterValue, but it has a fixed message "Bad request" while users should see that that the subset was too large.

GeoServer has a configuration option for setting the resource consumption limits https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/services/wcs/configuration.html#resource-consumption-limits but I do not know what error it is sending when to limits are exceeded. Hopefully it is something that helps users to locate what goes wrong, even it might be against the standard. Anyway, letting the server do work that will fail with the http 504 gateway timeout error is not a good option
[WCS request for large raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346065/wcs-request-for-large-raster).